# how to cin to int _value:1; C++

Tags: c++, integer, cin, cout

I have tried a code, It wanna use 1 byte of integer to save a number, how I can get value with **cin**, out value with **cout**

```
struct SoNguyen{
    int _value:1;
    void Input(){
         // How I can cin value to _value;
    }
    void Output(){
        // How I can cout value of _value;
    }
}
```

thks any got a tip.!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct SoNguyen{
    int _value:1;
    void Input(){
        int value;
        std::cin >> value;
        _value = value;
    }
    void Output(){
        std::cout << _value;
    }
};
```

The integer is by the way not 1 byte but 1 bit wide (think about why they called this feature *bit fields*). Bit fields however are bad programming practice and should be avoided as good as possible. If you need a member with the width of 1 byte, then rather use `std::int8_t` or `signed char`. If you need one with with the width of 1 bit, use `bool` (even though you waste 7 bits, it doesn't really matter on modern platforms).

A more C++ like approach to implement input / output of a class would contain operators:

```
struct SoNguyen{
    int _value:1;
};
template<typename CharT, typename CharTraits>
std::basic_istream<CharT, CharTraits>& operator>> (std::basic_istream<CharT, CharTraits>& Stream, SoNguyen& Object)
{
    int Value;
    Stream >> Value;
    Object._value = Value;
    return Stream;
}
template<typename CharT, typename CharTraits>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, CharTraits>& operator<< (std::basic_ostream<CharT, CharTraits>& Stream, SoNguyen const& Object)
{
    return Stream << Object._value;
}
```

The calling syntax would then look like this:

```
int main()
{
    SoNguyen foo;
    std::cin >> foo;
    std::cout << foo;
}
```

So it looks intuitive (since the same syntax also applies for fundamental types) and modular (you're able to write to and read from any stream).

Comment: Thks :)...

Số Nguyên <=> SoNguyen, it mean Integer of Vietnamese :D

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to read a primitive type - `int`, `char`, or `short`. Then assign the primitive type to the bit field.

```
void Input() {
   int i;
   std::cin >> i;
   _value = i;
}
```

or

```
void Input() {
   short i;
   std::cin >> i;
   _value = i;
}
```

etc.

The output is straight forward.

```
void Output() {
   std::cout << _value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :D
Số Nguyên <=> SoNguyen, it mean Integer of Vietnamese :D